# Where is the source of the python code that checks the function arguments?

Tags: python, function, arguments, parameter-passing, signature

When you call python function, it checks the arguments and raises `TypeError`s if you pass something that does not correspond to the function signature:

- `A takes from X to Y positional arguments but Z were given`
- `got multiple values for argument X`
- `got an unexpected keyword argument`

etc.

I want to see the code that performs those checks, so that I better understand how and when python performs them.

Answer (score 1):

In CPython implementation, the checks in question are performed by the 
[_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9ddb77741e041966d64739353393bcba33cc3bdd/Python/ceval.c#L4045) function. For example here is the [check for the number of positional arguments](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9ddb77741e041966d64739353393bcba33cc3bdd/Python/ceval.c#L4185)

Here is a part of the reference graph:

- [_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9ddb77741e041966d64739353393bcba33cc3bdd/Python/ceval.c#L4045)
- - [PyEval_EvalCodeEx](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9ddb77741e041966d64739353393bcba33cc3bdd/Python/ceval.c#L4321)
- - - [PyEval_EvalCode](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9ddb77741e041966d64739353393bcba33cc3bdd/Python/ceval.c#L716)
- - - - [run_eval_code_obj](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/44bfff2ec220f2e0291150a776d4d77af7c821ef/Python/pythonrun.c#L1096)
- - - - - [run_mod](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/44bfff2ec220f2e0291150a776d4d77af7c821ef/Python/pythonrun.c#L1127)
- - - - - [run_pyc_file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/44bfff2ec220f2e0291150a776d4d77af7c821ef/Python/pythonrun.c#L1147)
- - - - - - [PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/44bfff2ec220f2e0291150a776d4d77af7c821ef/Python/pythonrun.c#L374)
- - - - [exec_code_in_module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0fd2c300c2a85b3b227a907b2a39ef79fa86d850/Python/import.c#L976)
- - [_PyFunction_FastCallDict](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fb9423fd0a85f06affb8c3a8f25dd598a649aa42/Objects/call.c#L299)
- - - [function_call](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Objects/funcobject.c#L626)
- - - - [PyFunction_Type](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Objects/funcobject.c#L647)
- - - - - [PyFunction_NewWithQualName](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Objects/funcobject.c#L13)
- - - - - - [PyFunction_New](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Objects/funcobject.c#L78)
- - - - - - - [func_new_impl](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Objects/funcobject.c#L500)
- - - - - - - - [func_new](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3191391515824fa7f3c573d807f1034c6a28fab3/Objects/clinic/funcobject.c.h#L27)